# MAXDOP and Physical Cores

Tags: sql-server, parallelism, maxdop

I've got an instance built with 4 cores.  We have some queries that are going parallel.  I know changing the MAXDOP to 0 will single thread the queries.  My question is whether the 4 cores will no longer be utilized for multiple query execution?

My preference would be to isolate the parallel queries and if necessary manage them with Cost Threshold for Parallelism in order to single threading them.  I realize that this may impact other queries but it's a first line of investigation if my 1st question is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx) link (highlighting was mine):

> When an instance of SQL Server runs on a computer that has more than
>   one microprocessor or CPU, it detects the best degree of parallelism,
>   that is, **the number of processors employed to run a single statement**.
>
> Setting maximum degree of parallelism to 0 allows SQL Server to use
>   all the available processors up to 64 processors.
>
> To enable the server to determine the maximum degree of parallelism,
>   set this option to 0, the default value. **Setting maximum degree of
>   parallelism to 0 allows SQL Server to use all the available processors
>   up to 64 processors.** To suppress parallel plan generation, set max
>   degree of parallelism to 1. Set the value to a number from 1 to 32,767
>   to specify the maximum number of processor cores that can be used by a
>   single query execution. If a value greater than the number of
>   available processors is specified, the actual number of available
>   processors is used. If the computer has only one processor, the max
>   degree of parallelism value is ignored.
>
> You can override the max degree of parallelism value in queries by
>   specifying the MAXDOP query hint in the query statement.